# Rollover from workplace pension scheme to SIPP

Tags: united-kingdom, rollover, pension-sipp

If I stop working for an employer, can I transfer the funds from the employer's pension scheme to a SIPP without tax consequences? I think I should be able to because the funds in both schemes are pre-tax. But I am not sure of the mechanics of this.

Comment: Yes you can if you wish. Take care that the terms and conditions don't change in a way you care about e.g. if your existing pension allowed you to take it earlier than normal then moving it may mean you lose that.

Comment: [One arbitrariliy-chosen provider's information on transfers in](https://www.hl.co.uk/pensions/transfer-to-the-sipp)